# Value Error : One Hot Encoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have Label Encoded my info.venue column as follows, but when i try to do the One Hot Encoding it gives error. as 
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead.

```
df['info.venue']=labelencoder.fit_transform(df['info.venue'])
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder()
var1=onehotencoder.fit_transform(df['info.venue'])
```

My column is like this.

```
info.venue
Adelaide Oval
Brabourne Stadium
Kensington Oval, Bridgetown
Kingsmead
Melbourne Cricket Ground
Melbourne Cricket Ground
Melbourne Cricket Ground
Punjab Cricket Association IS Bindra Stadium, Mohali
R Premadasa Stadium
Saurashtra Cricket Association Stadium
Shere Bangla National Stadium
Stadium Australia
Sydney Cricket Ground
```

I want to encode this stadium names. 
But got value error.

Answer (score 3):

`OneHotEncoder` expects 2D array and you passed 1D (Series - resilt of `labelencoder.fit_transform`) - this can be fixed easily - use `df[['info.venue']]` instead of `df['info.venue']` (pay attention at square brackets) in the following way:

```
df['info.venue']=labelencoder.fit_transform(df['info.venue'])
R = onehotencoder.fit_transform(df[['info.venue']])
```

where R is a sparse 2D matrix:

```
In [155]: R
Out[155]:
<13x11 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 13 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [156]: R.A
Out[156]:
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

---

alternatively you can use [LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) in order to get One Hot Encoded values directly from strings:

Source DF:

```
In [121]: df
Out[121]:
                                info.venue
0                            Adelaide Oval
1                        Brabourne Stadium
2              Kensington Oval, Bridgetown
3                                Kingsmead
4                 Melbourne Cricket Ground
..                                     ...
8                      R Premadasa Stadium
9   Saurashtra Cricket Association Stadium
10           Shere Bangla National Stadium
11                       Stadium Australia
12                   Sydney Cricket Ground

[13 rows x 1 columns]
```

Solution:

```
In [122]: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

In [123]: lb = LabelBinarizer()

In [124]: r = pd.SparseDataFrame(lb.fit_transform(df['info.venue']),
     ...:                        df.index,
     ...:                        lb.classes_,
     ...:                        default_fill_value=0)
     ...:

In [125]: r
Out[125]:
    Adelaide Oval  Brabourne Stadium  Kensington Oval, Bridgetown  Kingsmead  Melbourne Cricket Ground  \
0               1                  0                            0          0                         0
1               0                  1                            0          0                         0
2               0                  0                            1          0                         0
3               0                  0                            0          1                         0
4               0                  0                            0          0                         1
..            ...                ...                          ...        ...                       ...
8               0                  0                            0          0                         0
9               0                  0                            0          0                         0
10              0                  0                            0          0                         0
11              0                  0                            0          0                         0
12              0                  0                            0          0                         0

    Punjab Cricket Association IS Bindra Stadium, Mohali  R Premadasa Stadium  Saurashtra Cricket Association Stadium  \
0                                                   0                       0                                       0
1                                                   0                       0                                       0
2                                                   0                       0                                       0
3                                                   0                       0                                       0
4                                                   0                       0                                       0
..                                                ...                     ...                                     ...
8                                                   0                       1                                       0
9                                                   0                       0                                       1
10                                                  0                       0                                       0
11                                                  0                       0                                       0
12                                                  0                       0                                       0

    Shere Bangla National Stadium  Stadium Australia  Sydney Cricket Ground
0                               0                  0                      0
1                               0                  0                      0
2                               0                  0                      0
3                               0                  0                      0
4                               0                  0                      0
..                            ...                ...                    ...
8                               0                  0                      0
9                               0                  0                      0
10                              1                  0                      0
11                              0                  1                      0
12                              0                  0                      1

[13 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: He's already using LabelEncoder to convert strings to numeric. So he only needs to convert the 1D data returned from the dataframe to 2D. :)

Comment: @VivekKumar, oh, i see it now (after the question has been properly formatted) - thank you! PS i've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: "  (0, 3) 1.0
  (1, 4) 1.0
  (2, 1) 1.0
  (3, 2) 1.0
  (4, 9) 1.0
  (5, 4) 1.0
  (6, 6) 1.0
  (7, 7) 1.0
  (8, 8) 1.0
  (9, 0) 1.0
  (10, 4) 1.0
  (11, 10) 1.0
  (12, 5) 1.0"
 Why i am getting output like this ??

Comment: I changed my code into this.. basically added '[[' brackets instead on '['
"onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder()
df['info.venue']=onehotencoder.fit_transform(df[['info.venue']])"

Comment: @MayurMahajan, you can't assign 2D matrix (result of OneHotEncoding) to a single column

Comment: Can I use Sparse Matrix 'r' in my decision tree ?

Comment: @MayurMahajan, yes, you can

Comment: Its giving me this error: 
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
when I try to use sparse Matrix in decision Tree

Comment: @MayurMahajan, your original question has been answered. If you want to ask a new qustion - please open a new question, post there your code, small data sample and an error backtrace (if you have one...)

Comment: @MayurMahajan, `df['info.venue'].str.get_dummies()`

Comment: Will it produce same output as using oneHotEncoder ??

Comment: Coz it's converting only 1 one and all zeros.. which makes no sense to me.